# How to use python aiohttp library to download multiple webpages?

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, aiohttp

I'm try to asynchronously scrape data from a [leaderboard](http://thronebutt.com) for a video game.  There are weekly and daily challenges.  I've based my code so far on [this async client with semaphores](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html).  The difference is I'm trying to contain the end where the loop is used in a function.  Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(url, session, sem):
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)

async def fetch_pages(url,pages,session):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(LIMIT)

    for page in range(pages+1):
        task_url = urljoin(url,str(page))
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(task_url, session, sem))
        tasks.append(task)

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def leaderboard_crawler(date, entries=0, pages=1):
    website = "https://www.thronebutt.com/archive/"
    date_url = urljoin(website,date+"/")
    entries_per_page = 30
    number_of_entries = entries or pages * entries_per_page
    full_pages, last_page = divmod(number_of_entries,30)
    entry_list = [30 for x in range(full_pages)]
    if last_page != 0:
        entry_list.append(last_page)    

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_pages(date_url,pages,session))
        date_html = loop.run_until_complete(future)

    return date_html

def weekly_leaderboard(week, year, entries=0, pages=1):
    weekly_date = "{0:02d}{1}".format(week, year)
    return leaderboard_crawler(weekly_date,entries,pages)

def daily_leaderboard(day, month, year, entries=0, pages=1):
    daily_date = "{0:02d}{1:02d}{2}".format(day, month, year)
    return leaderboard_crawler(daily_date, entries, pages)
```

I think the problem is in the `asyncio.gather(*tasks)` portion in the fetch_urls function.  I can't figure out how to pass that to the `leaderboard_crawler`.  Right now `date_html` is None. I've tried `return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`, which returns an array of Nones.  I've also tried wrapping it in `asyncio.ensure_future` then passing it to `loop.run_until_complete` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple, you are missing `return` in your call stack:

```
async def bound_fetch(url, session, sem):
    async with sem:
        # await fetch(url, session)  # missing return
        return await fetch(url, session)  # this one is right

async def fetch_pages(url,pages,session):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(LIMIT)

    for page in range(pages+1):
        task_url = urljoin(url,str(page))
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(task_url, session, sem))
        tasks.append(task)

    # await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # missing return
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # this one is right.
```

The working example is here:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(url, session, sem):
    async with sem:
        return await fetch(url, session)

async def fetch_pages(url,pages,session):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(5)

    for page in range(pages+1):
        task_url = urljoin(url,str(page))
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(task_url, session, sem))
        tasks.append(task)

    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def leaderboard_crawler(date, entries=0, pages=1):
    website = "https://www.thronebutt.com/archive/"
    date_url = urljoin(website,date+"/")
    entries_per_page = 30
    number_of_entries = entries or pages * entries_per_page
    full_pages, last_page = divmod(number_of_entries,30)
    entry_list = [30 for x in range(full_pages)]
    if last_page != 0:
        entry_list.append(last_page)    

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_pages(date_url,pages,session))
        date_html = loop.run_until_complete(future)

    return date_html

def weekly_leaderboard(week, year, entries=0, pages=1):
    weekly_date = "{0:02d}{1}".format(week, year)
    return leaderboard_crawler(weekly_date,entries,pages)

def daily_leaderboard(day, month, year, entries=0, pages=1):
    daily_date = "{0:02d}{1:02d}{2}".format(day, month, year)
    return leaderboard_crawler(daily_date, entries, pages)
```